# To set operator value Dynamically instead of static value in VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, operator-overloading

I am doing some calculation using comparison operator in my code (> or <) . Currently I have '>' static written.For Ex.

```
  If Counter_1 > MaxAllow Then
           ' ......ASP.net code.
```

Now I want to make it dynamic.So,instead of '>' static value I have one variable which contains operation (> or <) dynamically from database.

Now How can I use this variable so that I can do calculation of variable (> or <)
For Ex .

```
If Counter_1 [variable] MaxAllow.
```

Here variable may be > or <.

Note : I am using ASP.Net 2.0 with Language VB.
Immediate help in this concern will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can do exactly what you want.

You could do it with a function like this:

```
Public Function GreaterThanLessThan(value1 As Integer, value2 As Integer, aOperator As Char) As Boolean
    If aOperator <> ">"c AndAlso aOperator <> "<"c Then
        'If we get here then the operator character wasn't > or <
        Throw New Exception("Invalid operator")
        Return False
    Else
        Return If(aOperator = ">"c, (value1 > value2), (value1 < value2))
    End If
End Function
```

Usage:

```
    If GreaterThanLessThan(Counter_1, Maxllow, ">"c) Then

    End If
```

This code would probably benefit from being an extenstion Method (with a shorter name):

```
<Extension()>
Public Function GtLt(value1 As Integer, value2 As Integer, aOperator As Char) As Boolean
...etc
```

So that you could then do this:

```
If Counter_1.GtLt(MaxAllow,">"c) Then
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.How ever,I want to use this variable opeartor directly i.e not in If ..else condition as I have same code irrespective of Operator is < or >.

Comment: What is an alternative,if any?

Comment: I posted an alternative

Comment: Ok I am trying this and let you know